# stack storing struct pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

The program is supposed to implement stack for storing and retrieving struct pointers. The struct contains  one int and two struct variables. Push function is working fine but when i pop the struct pointer and try to access data in it there is an execution error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define MAX 10
struct node *arr[MAX];
int top=-1;
struct node* pop(){
    if(top=-1)
        return NULL;
    else{
        return arr[top--];
    }
}
void push(struct node* d){
    if(top==MAX-1)
        return;
    else{
        arr[++top]=d;
    }
}
int main(){
    struct node* t = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    t->data=9;
    push(t);
    printf("%d",pop()->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `free`. Just something to think about as you continue to work on this.

Comment: And in C, don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: This simple mistake could have been easily found by using debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if( top = -1)
```

should be

```
if( top == -1 )
```

With `=` you are assigning `-1` to `top`. To check for equality, use `==`.